# Install R package from private svn

Tags: r, svn

I have a private svn accessible via `http` after a login and I am able to read it with a simple `curl`, like so:

```
curl --user username:password http://myrepo/mypackage/trunk
```

Is there a way to get the same behaviour and install the package in R using `install.packages()`?

The following returns a `401 Unauthorized` error:

```
install.packages("http://myrepo/mypackage/trunk", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
install.packages("http://myrepo/mypackage/trunk", repos = NULL, type = "source", method="curl", extra = "--user username:password")
```

Alternatively with the following the password is requested and typed interactively:

```
 install.packages("http://myrepo/mypackage/trunk", repos = NULL, type = "source", method="curl", extra = "--user=username --password=pwd")
```

Similarly it works with wget:

```
 install.packages("http://myrepo/mypackage/trunk", repos = NULL, type = "source", method="wget", extra = "--user=username")
```