# Error: Unable to install R package from private SVN server

Tags: r, curl, ssl-certificate, visualsvn-server, r-package

On my Windows 10 machine (x64), I am trying to install `R` package (inside `R Studio`) from our private SVN server (Visual SVN Server) using instructions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131939/install-r-package-from-private-svn). The server has a self signed certificate. To install the package, I am running the following command:

```
install.packages("https://~path_to_private_SVN/trunk", repos = NULL, type = "source", method="curl", extra = "--user my_username:my_password")
```

I get this error message:

```
 Installing package into ‘path_to_R_library/3.5’
    (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
    % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
     0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
HTTPS-proxy has similar options --proxy-cacert and --proxy-insecure.
Error in download.file(p, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  'curl' call had nonzero exit status
```

Clearly, `R Studio` is not happy with the SVN server certificate problem and I am unable to install R package. However, in the moment, I would like to ignore this certificate error issue of the SVN server. Is there a way to tell `install.packages()` not to perform `SSL certificate verification` for this SVN host? I am aware that another option to install `R` package could be `devtools::install_svn()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with server's certificate and it is not trusted. The error message in your question specifies resolution steps and a workaround. For example, you can disable certificate verification in `curl`:

> If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use 
>   the -k (or --insecure) option.

Please see [KB134: Configuring SSL Certificates for VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00134/) for information about setting up server certificate on the server.